# Problemas y dudas con PHP Laravel return response()

Tags: php, laravel-5

Estoy usando la versión de Laravel 5.6.40

He tenido ya bastantes problemas con el **(return response)** y he visto que este problema es muy recurrente, necesito cargar una imagen pero esta no se muestra:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para poder mostrar esa imagen me baso en los siguientes codigos:

La ruta:

```
Route::post("/image/file{filename}", "ImageController@getImage")-\>name('image.file');
//aqui especifico que el nombre del archivo {filename} se lo estoy pasando como parametro.
```

La vista:

```
<img src="{{ route('image.file',['filename' => $image->image_path]) }}"/>
```

Ya me cerciore de que lo que esta en $image->image_path esta correcto con un var_dump

El controllador:

```
public function getImage($filename){
$file = Storage::disk('images')-\>get($filename);
return response($file, 200);
}
/*La imagen esta subida en el disk Storage de laravel por eso lo del:
Storage::disk('images')->get($filename); 
ya probe que la imagen esta bien guardada en el disco.*/
```

ahora creo que el problema esta en el return, cuando abro la imagen que no se ve en una pestaña nueva aparece el siguiente error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea? ya probe:

return new Response($file, 200);

también:

return Response::($file, 200);

return response()->view(($file, 200);

return response()->download(($file, 200);
etc..

Me habré equivocado en algo? mucho texto? XD

¿Como funciona el response cuando quiero mostrar archivos?

ya he probado esto en otras ocasiones para mostrar imagenes y no me habia dado error

Comment: proba `return Response::download($file);` en el controlador

Comment: No me a funcionado

Comment: dice que el methodo no esta, estas agregando el `use` de la clase en la ruta??

Comment: Si ya importe esto use Illuminate\Http\Response;

Comment: en la ruta verifica que estes usando el use de ImageController

Comment: AAAAA Estoy utilizando el metodo post para pasar una información por la ruta, no me habia dado cuenta de eso -_- que tonto que soy.

Comment: Ya probe lo siguiente y me a cargado la imagen Route::get("/image/file{filename}", "ImageController@getImage")->name('image.file');

Comment: aunque todavia no se por que me pide que pase la información por get estritamente

Answer (score 1):

Cambia el metodo post por get:

```
Route::get("/image/file{filename}", "ImageController@getImage")->name('image.file');
```

y recuerda que :
El método GET coloca los parámetros dentro de la URI mientras que el método POST los agrega al cuerpo.

hablando conmigo mismo.